# How to crop user input in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to add some limits to `contenteditable='true'` `div` so when user inputs more characters than acceptable I have to reduce it to a limit value. The problem is that user input is not just text it is HTML so I cannot just do something like this:

```
textValue.substr(0, this.consts.MAX_LENGTH);
```

Because it can break HTML and user input will be incorrect. So How to reduce only text in this situation and not touch HTML structure? Please don't hesitate to ask question if it is not clear.

Comment: So you want to leave the HTML tags as-is and only truncate the text outside of the tags?

Comment: One approach you could use is to take the string of text and split it into an array. Then loop through the array and if the current array element is plain text (no HTML), truncate it. Otherwise, leave it alone. Then join the array back together and you should be good to go.